# Highlight two cells based on two conditions of two different cells

Tags: excel

Thank you all in advance.
Lets say we have a table with two columns

```
    Col A   Col B 

 1. Apple 100
 2. Ball 100
 3. Apple 200
 4. Cat 200
 5. Dog 400
 6. Apple 400
 7. Ear 500
 8. Ball 500
 9. Fish 600
 10. Gold 600
```

I want to highlight the whole row for these two true conditions:

1. If COL A is Apple, always highlight that ROW. Then,
2. Only when COL A = Apple, note down the value of COL B. And highlight all the ROWs having that value in COL B also.

So, in the end, I will have ROWs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 highlighted in above table.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in Cells A1:B10, select that range and then put this conditional formatting formula in:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"Apple",$B:$B,$B1)>0
```

Comment: Clever solution. The `>0` is actually superfluous, since any number greater than 0 is automatically considered `TRUE` in conditional formatting, and 0 is automatically considered `FALSE`. But that's just a small point. +1

Comment: Thanks. I tend to leave stuff like that in there because even though numbers count as true, it's a separate data type in my mind. I hate implicit conversion.

Comment: That's a fair point. I still up-voted, just thought I would clarify if you didn't know about this. With the `>0` probably technically is safer since it is explicit.